# Passing value from Razor to javascript function CRUD

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have a trouble when I try to pass values from razor to a javascript function.
This works

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-1" value="Delete" onclick="deletePill()" />
```

```
function deletePill() {
    console.log("Hola");
}
```

But when I do this it doesn't work

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-1" value="Delete" onclick="deletePill(@item.Id)" />" />
```

Or

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-1" value="Delete" onclick="deletePill()" data="@item.Id" />
```

```
function deletePill(Id) {
    console.log(Id);
}
```

What should I change or add for it works?

## I want passing values from Razor to javascript functions

The variables have values but it doesn't pass the values properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The variables have values but it doesn't pass the values properly. I want passing values from Razor to javascript functions.

Well, the way you are trying to pass value is incorrect. You ought to pass value using string literal because, while you are writing [Razor syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0) you are in C# mode so, you have to pass value through single qoutation as like `'YourValuee'`. In your scenario you should write as `onclick="deletePill('@item.Id')"`. Therefore, in your code, you are ceretainly,missing the single qoutation `''`

**Solution:**

HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-1" value="Delete From Razor To Js Func" onclick="deletePill('@item.ItemId')" />
```

Javascript:

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        //Function Button Delete
        function deletePill(Id) {
            alert("User Id:" + Id + " will be Deleted!");
            console.log(Id);
        }
       
    </script>
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on it you [could check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: I added the single quotation '' that you said and It worked for me. Thank you so much !

Comment: You are most welcome and glad to assist you on this.